# Is this LDAP authentication issue?

Tags: ldap, windows-server-2003, windows-authentication

we have LDAP Windows Server 2003 R2. It was working fine till now. The problem is that *sometimes* we cannot access the network based on LDAP authentication. For example:

1) got to \\192.168.1.5
2) enter cridentials
3) It is OK

At some point of time (random) we are not able to access \192.168.1.5
If we reenter the cridentials it will be fine. It also happens with Windows services which log on with LDAP users. We have to enter the service cridentials each time the service is restarted.

So, do you think that the problem can be something with LDAP authentication cache? What else can be wrong. We are experiencing this problem for 2-3 months and we cannot figure it out.

10x

Comment: I can add that this can be a problem with the DNS + LDAP. In the event viewer we see the error in the link bellow. Restarting the services do not resolve our problems :( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc735696(v=ws.10).aspx